# What kind of cable do I need to go from DVI-D (dual link) to DVI-I or DVI-D (both dual link)?

Tags: graphics-card, display, dvi, cable

I was wondering what cable I need to go from DVI-D (dual link) on my LG monitor to DVI-I or DVI-D (both dual link) on my GPU and on-board graphics, respectively.

I bought this DVI-D to DVI-D (both single link) cable ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0041BT21M](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0041BT21M)) a while ago, but when I plug it in my monitor just stays in power saving mode. Could the fact that the cable isn't dual link be the crux of the issue? If so, what cable do I need? Or should this cable work just fine and there are other things that go wrong?

Comment: What kind of monitor?  Neither the onboard nor the GPU connections work?  And the monitor is set to either DVI or auto-select?  Any DVI cable should be fine if the monitor is 1080p.  Though it's possible that the cable itself could be damaged somehow.

Comment: @Zel The monitor is an LG27EA33. And, yeah, when I switch to DVI mode on the monitor it just says it's in power saving mode. But what you're saying is that it should work with the cable that I linked? And I was thinking of the cable being damaged, but I don't know how likely that is and, if so, why the monitor would register that there is a DVI cable plugged in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which DVI cable should I buy for my set up (DVI-I Dual for GFX card, DVI-D for monitor)?](http://superuser.com/questions/89589/which-dvi-cable-should-i-buy-for-my-set-up-dvi-i-dual-for-gfx-card-dvi-d-for-m)